# Java HashMap nested generics with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I'm trying to make a hashmap of hashmap values containing hashsets of different subclasses of a custom class, like so:

```
HashMap<String, Hashmap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>> superMap
```

`AttackCard` has subclasses such as: `Mage`, `Assassin`, `Fighter`. Each HashMap in the superMap will only ever have HashSets containing a single subclass of `AttackCard`.

When I try putting a

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>
```

into superMap, I get a compiler error:
[image: comiler error]

below is the code where the error occurs:

```
public class CardPool {

private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>> attackPool =
    new HashMap<>();

private ArrayList<AuxiliaryCard> auxiliaryPool;

public CardPool() {
(line 24)this.attackPool.put("assassins", new AssassinPool().get());
/*  this.attackPool.put("fighters", new Fighter().getPool());
    this.attackPool.put("mages", new Mage().getPool());
    this.attackPool.put("marksmen", new Marksman().getPool());
    this.attackPool.put("supports", new Support().getPool());
    this.attackPool.put("tanks", new Tank().getPool());
*/  
    this.auxiliaryPool = new ArrayList<>(new AuxiliaryCard().getPool()); 
}
```

And here is a snippet of the AssassinPool get-method:

```
private HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>> pool = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>> get() {
        return pool;
    }
```

I'd like to comment that I could easily solve my problem and have a wonderfully working program by making all the AttackCardPools, such as AssassinPool, return and contain HashSets of AttackCard instead of their respective subclass. I'm trying to understand this compilation error, however :)

```
compilation error at line 24: error: no suitable method found for `put(String, HashMap<String,HashSet<Assassin>>>` 
this.attackPool.put("assassins", new AssassinPool(). get()); 
method HashMap.putp.(String, HashMap<String,HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>>` is not applicable (actual argument `HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>` cannot be converted to `HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>` by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: Post the exception stack trace here as text and not an image or a link to an image.

Comment: `a hashmap of hashmaps containing hashsets` --> too deep, you should try to write a custom object that handles values of your top-map.

Comment: compilation error at line 24: error: no suitable method found for put(String,
HashMap<String,HashSet<Assassin>>> this.attackPool.put("assassins", new AssassinPool().
get());

method HashMap.putp.(String, HashMap<String,HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>> is not applicable
(actual argument HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>> cannot be converted to HashMap<String,
HashSet<? extends AttackCard>> by method invocation conversion)

Comment: don't post images on SO, unless it is really an image. Write the error message in text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Multi-level wildcards* can be a bit tricky at times, when not dealt with properly. You should first learn how to read a multi-level wildcards. Then you would need to learn to interpret the meaning of `extends` and `super` bounds in multi-level wildcards. Those are important concepts that you must first learn before starting to use them, else you might very soon go mad.

**Interpreting a multi-level wildcard:**

**Multi-level wildcards* should be read top-down. First read the outermost type. If that is yet again a paramaterized type, go deep inside the type of that parameterized type. The understanding of the meaning of *concrete parameterized type* and *wildcard parameterized type* plays a key role in understand how to use them. For example:

```
List<? extends Number> list;   // this is wildcard parameterized type
List<Number> list2;            // this is concrete parameterized type of non-generic type
List<List<? extends Number>> list3;  // this is *concrete paramterized type* of a *wildcard parameterized type*.
List<? extends List<Number>> list4;  // this is *wildcard parameterized type*
```

First 2 are pretty clear.

Take a look at the 3rd one. How would you interpret that declaration? Just think, what type of elements can go inside that list. All the elements that are capture-convertible to `List<? extends Number>`, can go inside the outer list:

- `List<Number>` - Yes
- `List<Integer>` - Yes
- `List<Double>` - Yes
- `List<String>` - **NO**

**References:**

- [JLS §5.1.10 - Capture Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)
- [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html)

  - [Wildcard Capture](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Wildcard%20Capture)
- [IBM Developer Works Article - Understanding Wildcard Captures](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html)

Given that the 3<sup>rd</sup> instantiation of list can hold the above mentioned type of element, it would be wrong to assign the reference to a list like this:

```
List<List<? extends Number>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();  // Wrong
```

The above assignment should not work, else you might then do something like this:

```
list.add(new ArrayList<Float>());  // You can add an `ArrayList<Float>` right?
```

So, what happened? You just added an `ArrayList<Float>` to a collection, which was supposed to hold a `List<Integer>` only. That will certainly give you trouble at runtime. That is why it's not allowed, and compiler prevents this at compile time only.

However, consider the 4<sup>th</sup> instantiation of multi-level wildcard. That list represents a family of all instantiation of `List` with type parameters that are subclass of `List<Number>`. So, following assignments are valid for such lists:

```
list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
list4 = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

**References:**

- [What do multi-level wildcards mean?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20do%20multilevel%20wildcards%20mean?)
- [Difference between a `Collection<Pair<String,Object>>`, a `Collection<Pair<String,?>>` and a `Collection<? extends Pair<String,?>>`?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20various%20multi-level%20instantiations?)

---

**Relating to single-level wildcard:**

Now this might be making a clear picture in your mind, which relates back to the invariance of generics. A `List<Number>` is not a `List<Double>`, although `Number` is superclass of `Double`. Similarly, a `List<List<? extends Number>>` is not a `List<List<Integer>>` even though the `List<? extends Number>` is a superclass of `List<Integer>`.

**Coming to the concrete problem:**

You have declared your map as:

```
HashMap<String, Hashmap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>> superMap;
```

<sub>Note that there is **3-level of nesting** in that declaration. **Be careful**. It's similar to `List<List<List<? extends Number>>>`, which is different from `List<List<? extends Number>>`.</sub>

Now what all element type you can add to the `superMap`? Surely, you can't add a `HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>` into the `superMap`. Why? Because we can't do something like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>();   // This isn't valid
```

You can only assign a `HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>` to `map` and thus only put that type of map as value in `superMap`.

**Option 1:**

So, one option is to modify your last part of the code in `Assassin` class(I guess it is) to:

```
private HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>> pool = new HashMap<>();

public HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends AttackCard>> get() {
    return pool;
}
```

... and all will work fine.

**Option 2:**

Another option is to change the declaration of `superMap` to:

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ? extends HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>> superMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now, you would be able to put a `HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>` to the `superMap`. How? Think of it. `HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>` is capture-convertible to `HashMap<String, ? extends HashSet<? extends AttackCard>>`. Right? So the following assignment for the inner map is valid:

```
HashMap<String, ? extends HashSet<? extends AttackCard>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>();
```

And hence you can put a `HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>>` in the above declared `superMap`. And then your original method in `Assassin` class would work fine.

---

**Bonus Point:**

After solving the current issue, you should also consider to change all the concrete class type reference to their respective super interfaces. You should change the declaration of `superMap` to:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Set<? extends AttackCard>>> superMap;
```

So that you can assign either `HashMap` or `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`, anytype to the `superMap`. Also, you would be able to add a `HashMap` or `TreeMap` as values of the `superMap`. It's really important to understand the usage of [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I would like to comment that I'm initializing the superMap to be just "new Hashset<>()". The actual HashMaps contained in superMap come from other classes. like: superMap.put("key1", new OtherClass.getHashMap())

Comment: Also in the end the solution is a bit disappointing. Because the problem arose in the first place, because I wanted a strong type check in the respective subclasses. For instance AssassinPool should contain HashSet ONLY of Assassin

Comment: While my field in AssassinPool is HashMap<String, HashSet<Assassin>> I can't return it as HashMap<String, HashMap<? extends AttackCard>> :( I am depressingly confused

Comment: @user2651804 For the same reason you can't assign a `List<List<Integer>>` to a `List<List<? extends Number>>`. I've done some modification in my answer. Please take a look again. Earlier it was a bit messed out.

Comment: I've spend a long, long time starring blind at your answer. Have you maybe made a logical mistake? You're saying that the only thing that doesn't go into list3 is List<String>. But here in the comments you say that List<Integer> doesn't go into list 3 either?

Comment: @user2651804 You mixing both the statements. They mean different thing. There I said, you can add a `List<Integer>` to `List<List<? extends Number>>`. Here I'm saying that, you can't assign a `List<List<Integer>>` to a `List<List<? extends Number>>`. Both have different meanings.

Comment: Which leads to the simple question: what does <? extends SomeSuperclass> do?? (if it doesn't accept subclasses, that is) I will try to read some generics tutorials now

Comment: @user2651804 I guess yes. You should go through some tutorial, to grab a better understanding of bounded wildcards. You can also go through [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18474379/1679863) where I've explained in brief what they mean.

Comment: "you can add a List<Integer> to List<List<? extends Number>>." That's what I'm trying to do in my code?? it doesn't work!
I'm trying to add HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> to HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends Number>>> basically?? Is there some miscommunication going on? To my eyes these examples are in complete sync!!

Comment: @user2651804 Well, you're not doing the same thing. If you notice in my answer I said - there is 3-level of nesting (Be Careful). That is what makes both the examples different. Since `List<Integer>` is a subclass of `List<? extends Number>`, so you can add it to the given list. But again, a `HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>` is not a subclass of `HashMap<String, HashSet<? extends Number>>`. Although it's a subclass of `HashMap<String, ? extends HashMap<Integer>>`. Notice the position of `?`.

Comment: Yeah I see. I can't admit that I completely understand. I need some break/study time. A quick word along the way: couldn't my solution be as simple as changing the "? extends" declaration of superMap?

Comment: @user2651804 I've edited the answer to show how you can change the declaration of your `superMap` to allow your original method to work fine. Check the part of my answer below - **`Option 2`**.

Comment: Well, I haven't given it any thought yet, but it works like a charm. Wow, thank you so much for your time and everything! It's surprising that it took so long to get this question answered (I've asked several places, several times) Guess I'll have to study the answer and why it works later. And honestly I'm relieved I don't have to delve into generics, haha

Comment: @user2651804 haha :) You're welcome. But I would really suggest you to learn generics from basics. It is really an interesting topic, and very important one. You can start from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer. Unfortunately it was CW'd by so many edits. Try flagging a mod and asking to have it un-CW'd.

Comment: @PaulBellora Oh! Didn't notice I've edited it 11 times. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `HashSet<? extends AttackCard>`, just use `HashSet<AttackCard>` in all declarations - the superMap and all Sets being added.

You can still store subclasses of `AttackCard` in a `Set<AttackCard>`.

---

You should be declaring your variables using the *abstract* type, not the concrete implantation, ie:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<? extends AttackCard>>> superMap
```

See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Although changing `HashSet<? extends AttackCard>` to `HashSet<AttackCard>` will allow him to add subclasses in the set. But this will not allow to add a `HashSet<Assassin>` into that `map`.

Comment: @RohitJain I'm suggesting *all* declarations be `Set<AttackCard>` everywhere.

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah fine. But I guess you the declaration should be - `Map<String, Map<String, Set<AttackCard>>>`. But you can't put a `HashSet<Assassin>` in the inner map. That was what I was saying.

Comment: Okay, before I go diving deep into generic classes, could you confirm that I wouldn't have a problem at all if my map wasn't 2 levels? I mean if I wanted HashMap<String, AttackCard> I could add Assassin to key1 and Fighter to key2 without problems?

Comment: @user2651804 Yes you can. I would suggest you to go through some generics tutorial before starting using multi-level wildcards.

Comment: above comment was meant to be posted to Rohit Jain's answer =]

Answer (score 0):

Probably a question of covariance, you need to replace ? `extends` by `? super`.

See [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: After my failed attempt at understanding the thread, I just went ahead an replaced extends with super. I get the same compilation error =/