# Trouble with generics and variable assignment

Tags: java, generics

I have two maps `Something1` and `Something2`. Both extend the Class `Something`.

```
Map<Class<? extends Something1>, String> m1
Map<Class<? extends Something2> ,String> m2
```

I want to create a more generic map `m3` to which I can assign `m1` or `m2` like this:

```
Map<Class<? extends Something>, String> m3 = m1;
```

However I get the following exception:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Class<? extends Something1>, String> to Map<Class<? extends Something>, String>
```

I also tried using `Class<?>` but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Read this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19220458/1679863, to understand how multilevel generic types work. After that, you would be able to understand that changing your 3rd map to: `Map<? extends Class<? extends Something>, String> = m1;` would work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. Consider the following:

```
Map<Class<? extends Something1>, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put(Something1.class, "Something1"); // OK
m1.put(Something2.class, "Something2"); // Error
```

So, you can't put `Something2` as the key.

The other way around:

```
Map<Class<? extends Something2>, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put(Something1.class, "Something1"); // Error
m2.put(Something2.class, "Something2"); // OK
```

Here, you can't put `Something1` as the key.

But, if you create a version that uses the base class as the wildcard it works. Check this out:

```
Map<Class<? extends Something>, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(Something1.class, "Something1"); // OK
m.put(Something2.class, "Something2"); // OK
```

Your problem is then that you are trying to assign a more specific type to the generic type. Like this:

```
m = m1; // Boom, but why?
```

Why does that not work. Well, it is because if you allow that assignment you would be able to do this:

```
m.put(Something2.class, "Something2");
```

Which obviously would not be ok since then you would put `Something2` as the key for a `Something1`-type Map.

Answer (score 0):

Non-wildcard type arguments must be exactly the same to be compatible. `Class<? extends Something1>` is not exactly the same as `Class<? extends Something>` (even though one is a subtype of the other), and therefore, a `Map` of one is not compatible with a `Map` of the other.

If you want a type that can accept `Map`s with different type arguments, you need a wildcard at the top level (though note that this will effectively make the `Map` read-only):

```
Map<? extends Class<? extends Something>, String> m3 = m1;
```