# Java generics assignability

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, generic-collections

I am struggling a bit on assign-ability of generic type parameters.

Here are how my type definitions look:

```
public static interface CellValue<T> {
    T getValue();
    Class<?> getType();
}

public static class DoubleCell implements CellValue<Double> {
    Double value;

    public DoubleCell(Double value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType() {
        return Double.class;
    }
}

public static class FormulaCell implements CellValue<String> {
    String value;

    public FormulaCell(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

Now, why do the following declarations work (to me, this is expected behaviour, but I may have misunderstood why it works)

```
Map<String, ? extends CellValue<?>> m = new HashMap<String, FormulaCell>();
Map<String, ? extends CellValue<?>> m2 = new HashMap<String, DoubleCell>();
```

..while the following do not?

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, ? extends CellValue<?>>> n = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, FormulaCell>>();
Map<Integer, Map<String, ? extends CellValue<?>>> n2 = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, DoubleCell>>();
```

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219635/java-hashmap-nested-generics-with-wildcards) be helpful?

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. Nested wildcards are something I'll try to stay away from.

Answer (score -2):

Try `Map<Integer,`***`? extends`***`Map<String, ? extends CellValue<?>>>` instead.